# How to get questions belonging to particular tags

Tags: support, tags, notifications

How can I be notified of questions which belong to only particular tags?
I need to get all the question notifications for particular tags, for example Java,
I would like to answer to all those questions related to Java.

Comment: ask this in meta

Comment: "I would like to answer to all those questions" - good luck... you'll need it.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: you can simply click on the tag and you will only see questions with that tag...  for example - [java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [java](/questions/tagged/java), you will see all the new questions tagged "java"; if you want a feed, then https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java&sort=newest is the feed for the new questions for that tag.

Comment: Is there any option to  automatically notify rather go and click on the Java tagged button?

Comment: If you look at the page for [tag:java], you will notice that a number will be added to the title, when a new question is posted. Otherwise, you need a RSS reader that notify you of new questions.

Comment: Ok. thanks. Now clear.